# How to Traverse to the Child Node and modify it in SOA BPEL/XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, bpel, oracle-soa

I need to know how i can Modify the below in Oracle SOA BPEL/XSLT
Version12c. I have the below xsl in a properly defined variable based on the schema

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <country>America</country>        
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>
      <cost>50</cost>
      <tax>50</tax>
    </price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <country>Aus</country>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>
      <cost>100</cost>
      <tax>10</tax>
    </price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I need to change the tax rate just for country AUS like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <country>Aus</country>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>
      <cost>100</cost>
      <tax>50</tax>
    </price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Can anyone help me on how to just change a child field value in oracle BPEl or XSLT

Comment: Why does your output show changes to the first book too?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  But, this works.

```
  <xsl:template match="book[country = 'Aus']/price/tax">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="50"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand what does this means select="node()|@*"/>

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT

Comment: Would there be any significant performance difference by using <xsl:template match="tax[ancestor::book/country='Aus']"> instead of <xsl:template match="book[country = 'Aus']/price/tax">?

Comment: Sebastien,  The way my answer is written the XSLT will do one pass through the XML.  The way you've suggested is one pass through the XML plus every time a tax node is encountered the path searches all of tax ancestors.  So, there's a performance hit.  Whether it is significant or not depends on the size of the XML file.  It's probably not though.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with this reasoning. When `xsl:apply-templates` is executed with a `tax` element included in the list of nodes to process, the processor needs to find all templates that match `tax` and select the best among them. In order to determine if the pattern `book[country = 'Aus']/price/tax`matches it, the processor needs to go up the tree. At least that's how it's described by the XSLT processing model. In practice, performance is processor-specific and a processor may be using optimization to avoid this - but then it could equally well optimize for the alternative pattern too.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the clarification.  After I wrote the comment I was wondering about that.  At least the processor only goes up the tree until it finds one price and one book.  Correct me if I'm wrong, it seems using ancestor::book would go all of the way up the tree.  Do you know if ancestor::book[1] would be more efficient?  To truly only have one trip through the XML I would use a mode on apply-templates within a book[country = 'Aus'] template.  The mode would have an identity template and a tax template.  Do you agree with that?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. It seems reasonable that `ancestor::book[1]` would be more efficient - but for all I know, the processor could have the entire ancestor axis already lined up and "see" immediately that there is only one `book` on it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks again.